# Speeding up a stream like data type

Tags: performance, haskell, stream, pipeline, fold

I've made a type which is supposed to emulate a "stream". This is basically a list without memory.

```
data Stream a = forall s. Stream (s -> Maybe (a, s)) s
```

Basically a stream has two elements. A state `s`, and a function that takes the state, and returns an element of type `a` and the new state.

I want to be able to perform operations on streams, so I've imported `Data.Foldable` and defined streams on it as such:

```
import Data.Foldable

instance Foldable Stream where
  foldr k z (Stream sf s) = go (sf s)
    where
      go Nothing = z
      go (Just (e, ns)) = e `k` go (sf ns)
```

To test the speed of my stream, I've defined the following function:

```
mysum = foldl' (+) 0
```

And now we can compare the speed of ordinary lists and my stream type:

```
x1 = [1..n]
x2 = Stream (\s -> if (s == n + 1) then Nothing else Just (s, s + 1)) 1

--main = print $ mysum x1
--main = print $ mysum x2
```

My streams are about half the speed of lists (full code [here](http://ideone.com/YQAock)).

Furthermore, here's a best case situation, without a list or a stream:

```
bestcase :: Int
bestcase = go 1 0 where
  go i c = if i == n then c + i else go (i+1) (c+i)
```

This is a lot faster than both the list and stream versions.

So I've got two questions:

1. How to I get my stream version to be at least as fast as a list.
2. How to I get my stream version to be close to the speed of `bestcase`.

Answer (score 4):

As it stands the `foldl'` you are getting from `Foldable` is defined in terms of the foldr you gave it. The default implementation is the brilliant and surprisingly good

```
foldl' :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldl' f z0 xs = foldr f' id xs z0
  where f' x k z = k $! f z x
```

But foldl' is the specialty of your type; fortunately the `Foldable` class includes `foldl'` as a method, so you can just add this to your instance.

```
 foldl' op acc0 (Stream sf s0) = loop s0 acc0
   where 
    loop !s !acc = case sf s  of 
      Nothing -> acc
      Just (a,s') -> loop s' (op acc a)
```

For me this seems to give about the same time as `bestcase`
Note that this is a standard case where we need a strictness annotation on the accumulator. You might look in the `vector` package's treatment of a similar type https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.12.2/docs/src/Data-Vector-Fusion-Stream.html for some ideas; or in the hidden 'fusion' modules of the text library https://github.com/bos/text/blob/master/Data/Text/Internal/Fusion .